# miktex texworks Application is not opening

Tags: texworks

I am using miktex on window 10 and it's texworks application is not opening. I do uninstall the miktex Application and install it again but issue is not resolve. Please help how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE. Please note that TEXworks is in no way related to MIKTEX. So your question has nothing to do with TEX engine. Also, I have removed irrelevant tags.

Comment: Ok thanks i am new to latex so that's i didn't know about this... Now why texworks is not opening... any idea

Comment: no idea, do you have any error reports? did you try reinstalling?